# Samba server issues

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I have setup a new linux box that I am tinkering with. One item that I have always setup is samba so that I can easily copy files to and from the server.

The reason I bring this topic up is I am not able to browse to the samba shares from my windows machine.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

The issue that I am having is when I start the server, the server starts, but in the /var/log/samba/smbd.log I get this error:

```
[2009/12/14 23:23:00,  0] smbd/server.c:456(smbd_open_one_socket)
smbd_open_once_socket: open_socket_in: Address already in use

[global]
dns proxy = No
log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
load printers = No
smb ports = 139
server string = WWW Server
unix password sync = yes
force group = mediauser
workgroup = WORKGROUP
force user = mediauser
domain master = Yes
encrypt passwords = yes
valid users = mediauser,devroot
realm = devstation
preferred master = Yes
directory mode = 777
wins support = Yes
hosts allow = 192.168.1.



[video]
writeable = yes
path = /mediacenter/video
force directory mode = 0777
force create mode = 0777
create mask = 0777
comment = Video
directory mask = 0777
public = yes
allow hosts = 192.168.1.
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, 'netstat -pl' will show you listening ports with process names when run as root.

Figure out which process is on that port and kill it. It's quite likely to be another instance of smbd. Kill that process and start your own, or kill -HUP the process to re-read the configuration file.

Comment: I have looked at the listening ports and I only see one samba running

tcp6       0      0 [::]:netbios-ssn        [::]:*                  LISTEN      14672/smbd

Comment: You'll want to kill that process, 14672, then try to start smbd again.

Comment: I killed the process and I no longer get the Address already in use
error, but now I get the error [2009/12/15 13:36:14, 0] smbd/service.c:make_connection_snum(620)
Can't become connected user!

Comment: Well, that's a new and entirely separate issue -- are you running as root? Not so sure about troubleshooting that problem; maybe a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the Samba port (139) is already in use.  You can find the used ports by:

```
netstat -vatn
```

Make sure nothing is running on 139 (ie: Local Address :::139).  Specifically VMware will install it's own Samba and take up that port.

Comment: I am not running VMware on this machine, it is a base install of ubuntu, I installed samba and ran updates. 

While look at netstat I see the following:

tcp6      0      0  :::139      :::*      LISTEN

Answer (score 0):

explanation + workaround:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=726936